# Varchar como Clave Primaria

Tags: mysql, sql

Hola hice una base de datos en base a un proyecto que encontre en Internet para hacer un REST. 
  El problema que tengo es que la Clave Primaria es de tipo `varchar` y no la puedo auto-incrementar ya que Mysql no me deja. Tengo que hacer la insercion manual.

¿ Como puedo hacer para auto-incrementarla manualmente ? Estuve viendo que con los triggers se podria hacer pero no tuve suerte.

Las tablas son estas:

```
 Tabla T_Reserva

fechaLlegada: Date
numNoches: integer
numAdultos: integer
numMenDos: integer
numMenDosDoce: integer
localizador: String
observaciones: String
precio: Double
régimen: String
codCliente: String
codHotel: String
tipoHab: String
Clave primaria: localizador
Clave foránea hacia T_Cliente codCliente
Clave foránea hacia T_Hotel codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_TipHab tipoHab, codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_Tarifa fechaLlegada, regimen, tipoHab, codHotel 

Como clave primaria alternativa tenemos, codigoHotel, codigoCliente,
FechaLlegada, pero de esta manera sólo puede haber un reserva para un cliente en
una fecha determinada.
```

Deberia cambiar las Claves Primarias a `integer`. Porque a los mejor las puso de tipo `varchar` por alguna razon.

Gracias.

```
Tabla T_Cliente

codCliente: String
nombre: String
apellido: String
dirección: String
provincia: String
país: String
código postal: String
teléfono: String
móvil: String
email: String
Clave primaria: codCliente 

Tabla T_TarCre

número: String
caducidad: String
tipo: String
codCliente: String
Clave primaria: número
Clave foránea hacia T_Cliente codCliente 

Tabla T_Hotel

codigoHotel: String
Nombre: String
fechaMaxEntrada: Date
numMaxNoches : integer
Clave primaria: codHotel 

Tabla T_TipHab

tipo: String
numMáxPersonas: integer
disponibilidad: integer
codHotel: String
precio: real
Clave primaria: tipo, codHotel
Clave foránea hacia T_Hotel codHotel
Tabla T_Tarifa
precioNoche: Double
fechaInicio: Date
fechaFin: Date
regimen: String
tarifa: Double
codHotel: String
tipoHab: String
Clave primaria: fechaInicio, regimen, tipoHab, codHotel,
Clave foránea hacia T_TipHab tipoHab, codHotel
```

Comment: la creaste como `varchar`, pero es un número?....en ese caso no sería más fácil simplemente crearla como `int` y usar así un autoincrementador?

Comment: Es que en el proyecto que saque de internet estaban creadas asi. Lo quise crear al pie de la letra para no tener problemas.

Comment: No se porque razon las abra creado con `varchar`.

Comment: ... Nunca es tarde para cambiarlo, encontrarte con los problemas que querías evitar, y solucionarlos.

Comment: Si estas siguiendo una guía es bueno que evalúes el código para saber en que forma se manejara el auto-incremento en la base de datos, ya sea del lado del código o la BD, también debes saber que no todas las llaves primarias son números también es muy aceptado que sean código alfanuméricos generados aleatoriamente como son los universally unique identifier (UUID) que lo encuentras en todo lenguaje de programación y ademas las base de datos te ofrece un generador UUID entre sus librerías.

Comment: que problemas presentas si cambias tu varchar a int?

Comment: Si estas siguiendo una guia, las claves estan como varchar, y no hay una explicacion contundente sobre el porque.. no parece ser una muy buena guia a seguir... en la gran mayoria de las veces las claves son numeros (int o el que gustes para un entero)

Comment: Yo lo que hice del lado del codigo fue hacer un static que se vaya incrementando y luego insertarlo en la BD ( pero claro.. cuando se cierra el programa se reinicializa... ), ya que la guia es un proyecto que muestra mas el concepto, hay muestras de codigo solamente..¿En que casos es util una `Primary Key` de tipo `varchar`..? ¿Y como logro auto-incrementarla?.. Ya que el nombre de la columna con `varchar` se llama `localizador`, es decir quiza es util par localizar alguna reserva... Gracias

Answer (score 2):

No puedes aplicar un `AUTO_INCREMENT` a una cadena de texto en SQL , es solo aplicable para `INTEGERS` no se por que el creador del proyecto habrá dejado esas llaves primarias como `VARCHAR`, no me parece lógico. Y como recomendación, es bueno que evalues el código de un proyecto que hayas sacado de Internet, de esa forma te evitas situaciones como esta. Un abrazo